# How to preform transformations on the part whrere a specific turning point exists in a polynomial function

Tags: polynomials

I know that a polynomial function of degree n has at most n-1 turning points

I know how to perform transformations on the polynomial function as a whole but not on a specific part (the part where specific turning point exists)

[image]
Take a look at this image for example.
How do I stretch this part of graph across the y-axis? (or any other transformation in general. I want to get grasp of the idea)

Why I am asking?

I want to be able to control the shape of the curve I am fitting when performing non-linear regression

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not always true that a polynomial of degree $n$ has $n-1$ turning points. Have a look at $x^3+x$.

Comment: **at most^** n-1 turning points

Comment: Do you mean move one turning point up or down and leave the other turning point fixed?

Comment: If you change the values of the polynomial on just part of the real line, the resulting function will not be a polynomial.

Comment: @steven gregory thx for clarification,  I will edit the question.

Comment: @steven gregory yes , exactly or any other transformation

Comment: @Rob Arthan do you mean a piecewise function?

Comment: Of possible use might be some of [James Frederick Blinn's essays/columns in **IEEE Computer Graphics and Applications**](https://dblp.org/pid/b/JamesFBlinn.html), especially those from 1999.

Comment: Let me put it another way: two polynomials of degree no greater than $n$ that agree at $n+1$ points are identical. Maybe a piecewise polynomial function is what you are looking for.

Comment: If you want a cubic polynomial with the point (0,0) fixed, then $f(x) = ax^3+bx^2 + cx$. If you also want $f'(0) = 0$, then you need $c=0$. Is that what you are getting at? I don't know. Your question doesn't actually have any useful information in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this as an answer because it's too much text for a comment.

Your thinking is too fuzzy.

> *I know how to perform transformations on the polynomial function as a
> whole but not on a specific part (the part where specific turning
> point exists)*

The word transformation has many meanings and many applications. You need to be specific.

- What is the reason for these transformations.
- - Is this a physical model of the behavior of some object?
- - Is this a statistical model of some data?
- - Is this a mathematical model of a family of functions.
- What are the rules for these transformations.
- - Can we translate, skew, rotate, ..., them?
- - Must they be continuous, differentiable, piecewise continuous, ... ?

An example would be nice.

What you have specifically tried and why you didn't like the results.

Comment: "Why I am asking? I want to be able to control the shape of the curve I am fitting when performing non-linear regression" so yeah, statistical models